# Subview height resize

Tags: xcode, uiview, hidden

I have a UIView with 2 subviews. Only 1 subview is visible at a time, controlled by a segmented control. The subviews have different heights. How do I set the UIView height to be dependent on the visible subview?

EDIT - 
The below code works for the initial back and forth segue of the segmented control but then stays at 30px. The debugger shows that there is an issue satisfying the constrains but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Error:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
("<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f84f84b3b80 V:[UIView:0x7f84f852bc60(60)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f84f8494d20 V:[UIView:0x7f84f852bc60(30)]>")

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f84f84b3b80 V:[UIView:0x7f84f852bc60(60)]>
```

Code:

```
- (IBAction)segmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        [_ParentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [_ParentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:_ParentView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:nil
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:30.0]];

        self.1stView.hidden = NO;
        self.2ndView.hidden = YES;
        break;
    case 1:
        [_ParentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [_ParentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:_ParentView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:60.0]];

        self.1stView.hidden = YES;
        self.2ndView.hidden = NO;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably not the cleanest but I was able to get the below code to work. Thanks to @AJB for the help.

```
- (IBAction)segmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        self.1stView.hidden = NO;
        self.2ndView.hidden = YES;

        _1stconstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintWithItem:_ParentView
                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                       toItem:nil
                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                       multiplier:1.0
                       constant:30.0];

        [_ParentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [_ParentView removeConstraint:_2ndconstraint];
        [_ParentView addConstraint:_1stconstraint];

        break;
    case 1:
        self.1stView.hidden = YES;
        self.2ndView.hidden = NO;

        _2ndconstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:_ParentView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:60.0];

        [_ParentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [_ParentView removeConstraint:_1stconstraint];
        [_ParentView addConstraint:_2ndconstraint];

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I set this up in storyboard and got it to work.

So you have your three UIViews for the story board

in your .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *parentView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *HDDView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *SSDView;
```

Then in your .m file

```
@synthesize parentView, HDDView, SSDView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //so here you can set which uiview is hidden when the view loads
    //or you probably did it in your storyboard, either way works
    self.SSDView.hidden = YES;

}

- (IBAction)segmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
 switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
     case 0:
         self.HDDView.hidden = NO;
         self.SSDView.hidden = YES;


         CGRect newFrame = parentView.frame;
         newFrame.size.height = HDDView.frame.size.height;
         parentView.frame = newFrame;

         break;
     case 1:
         self.HDDView.hidden = YES;
         self.SSDView.hidden = NO;

         CGRect otherFrame = parentView.frame;
         otherFrame.size.height = SSDView.frame.size.height;
         parentView.frame = otherFrame;

         break;
     default:
     break;
     }
 }
```

Now in your storyboard add your SSDView and HDDView UIViews and hook them up to their IBOutlets. Then add your parentView UIView and hook it up too. Then drag SSDView and HDDView inside of the parentView UIView. **Make sure that you put SSDView and HDDView at the top of the parentView so that each UIView's top bounds are flush. Also make sure that you did not drag one of subviews into the other. And finally add some constraints to the parentView so that it is in the position that you will want. Then hook up your segmented controller and you are good to go.

All in all, I would suggest not to use Interface Builder for complex things like this. You can do this with code and it will be much more customizable and easier to adjust. I started out using IB but it is much better to do these things programmatically because you can have much more control. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for responding. They are all plain UIViews. So in your example yourImage would be he subview and yourUIView would be the parent view? Or is yourUIView the temporary view?
Thanks

Comment: @JasonBestor I changed my answer for UIViews now. yourUIView is the parent view and yourUISubView would be the view that you are adding to the parent view.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work and I think its because my view and subviews have already been created in the storyboard. Each subview contains a textbox and button but the 1st subview is 30px high and the second is 60px. The parent view they are in has autoresize dependencies that I am trying to move down when the segmented control is switched and swaps which subview is hidden.
I hope that clarifies...
Thanks again

Comment: @JasonBestor Can you post what code you have? This way I can see how you are doing it and help you out more.

Comment: I wish I could but its mostly in the storyboard in the way I explained above. The code is just the segmented view action.
Code posted in question

Comment: I think I found a method that will work but its creating a constraint conflict. Please see my edits above.
Thanks

Comment: I just saw your changed answer above. I will try it out.
Thanks

Comment: ah sorry I forgot to comment to let you know. Hope it works out

Comment: Thanks but it still didn't work for me. There are no errors but the parentView doesn't expand. Thanks for trying.